# Can I get all active ARB subscription in a single API call

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

Current I'm exporting all ARB data by calling API to get all active ARB ids then go through each ARB id to get info stored in each ID. But this process is too long and it makes lots of requests. Is there any way so that I can get all active ARB ids data in one request like that of any database?

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-get-a-list-of-subscriptions

This function gives only small amount data while I need complete data stored in a profile like this one: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-get-subscription
But this function only works for single ID.

Answer (score 2):

**New Answer**

No. The `ARBGetSubscriptionListRequest` only returns a limited amount of information. If you want detailed information you would need to call `ARBGetSubscriptionListRequest` and then loop through the results and make an API call for each subscription to get the more granular data.

Due to the potentially large amount of results, you probably should store the results in a database and then have a bunch of scheduled scripts make the subsequent API calls.

**Old Answer**

Yes. You can call [`ARBGetSubscriptionListRequest`](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-get-a-list-of-subscriptions).

Request:

```
{
    "ARBGetSubscriptionListRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "5KP3u95bQpv",
            "transactionKey": "346HZ32z3fP4hTG2"
        },
        "refId": "123456",
        "searchType": "subscriptionActive",
        "sorting": {
            "orderBy": "id",
            "orderDescending": "false"
        },
        "paging": {
            "limit": "1000",
            "offset": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "totalNumInResultSet": 1273,
    "totalNumInResultSetSpecified": true,
    "subscriptionDetails": [
        {
            "id": 100188,
            "name": "subscription",
            "status": "canceled",
            "createTimeStampUTC": "2004-04-28T23:59:47.33",
            "firstName": "Joe",
            "lastName": "Tester",
            "totalOccurrences": 12,
            "pastOccurrences": 6,
            "paymentMethod": "creditCard",
            "accountNumber": "XXXX5454",
            "invoice": "42820041325496571",
            "amount": 10,
            "currencyCode": "USD"
        },
        {
            "id": 100222,
            "name": "",
            "status": "canceled",
            "createTimeStampUTC": "2004-10-22T21:00:15.503",
            "firstName": "asdf",
            "lastName": "asdf",
            "totalOccurrences": 12,
            "pastOccurrences": 0,
            "paymentMethod": "creditCard",
            "accountNumber": "XXXX1111",
            "invoice": "",
            "amount": 1,
            "currencyCode": "USD"
        },
        {
            "id": 100223,
            "name": "",
            "status": "canceled",
            "createTimeStampUTC": "2004-10-22T21:01:27.69",
            "firstName": "asdf",
            "lastName": "asdf",
            "totalOccurrences": 12,
            "pastOccurrences": 1,
            "paymentMethod": "eCheck",
            "accountNumber": "XXXX3888",
            "invoice": "",
            "amount": 10,
            "currencyCode": "USD"
        }
    ],
    "refId": "123456",
    "messages": {
        "resultCode": "Ok",
        "message": [
            {
                "code": "I00001",
                "text": "Successful."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives very small amount of data. Is it possible to get bulk data from this one: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-get-subscription

Comment: No. If you want that much detail for every subscription you will need to make an API for each subscription returned by `ARBGetSubscriptionListRequest.`

Comment: Thanks for this info. I will continue with my current python script to grab one by one. But if they had bulk export then it would have lowered the API calls.